# Tuple unpacking and np.max() giving unexpected values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tuples

I have a dataset that I am trying to filter and apply an adjustment value using tuples.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'loannum': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    'or_dep': [250000, 650000, 1000000, 300000]
})

loan2adj = [('1', 50000), ('3', 250000), ('2', 100000)]
```

My expected output looks like this.

```
loannum      or_dep
1            200000
2            550000
3            750000
4            300000
```

This is the logic I'm using to unpack the tuples and apply the adjustment value.

```
for loan, adj_amt in loan2adj:
    df.loc[df['loannum'] == loan, 'or_dep'] = np.max(df['or_dep'] - adj_amt, 0)
```

This code produces some unusual values.

```
loannum     or_dep
1           950000
2           550000
3           750000
4           300000
```

Loans 3 and 4 are being returned correctly. Loan 4 should not have an adjustment and loan 3 is being adjusted correctly. How can I achieve the desired output?

Comment: `df['or_dep'] - adj_amt` -- you're not selecting a specific row here.

Comment: You might be looking for `np.maximum`, not `np.max`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `np.max(df['or_dep'] - adj_amt, 0)` you are not selecting the wanted row.

To fix it just:

```py
for loan, adj_amt in loan2adj:
    df.loc[df['loannum'] == loan, 'or_dep'] = np.max(df.loc[df['loannum'] == loan, 'or_dep'] - adj_amt, 0)
```

You probably should use the `loannum` column as an index to simplyfy your locs:

```py
df.set_index("loannum", inplace=True)
for loan, adj_amt in loan2adj:
    df.loc[loan, 'or_dep'] = max(df.loc[loan, 'or_dep'] - adj_amt, 0)
```